# Set element to top of viewport in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a property I can use or function to act as "top:0" but top of viewport instead of top of the page.

Comment: The only time "top: 0" means top of the viewport is when you use `position: fixed`

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `position: fixed` on your element.

Comment: Much obliged, I was using absolute to get the same affect, but fixed will work fine. Thank you.