# how in javascript/jquery do I show a pop-up element relative to the viewport, rather than the web-page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, element, viewport

I have a web-page that contains a table of videos and pictures, which when any one of these items is clicked, the clicked item shows in a floating pop-up display area, but currently this area shows near the top of the web-page, so is often partially off screen when the user has the web-page scrolled so that the table of videos and pictures is fully scrolled into view, and so the user has to scroll the page up to view the floating pop-up display area, away from the row item they clicked in the table, where they can edit information concerning that item.

I would rather that the pop-up display area be displayed near the top of the viewport, so that it can fully be seen without the user having to scroll it into view, and the table of videos and pictures now under the pop-up display stay where it was before the user clicked any of the items in the table.

I've seen this topic [Set element to top of viewport in javascript [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21528057/set-element-to-top-of-viewport-in-javascript), but I don't want to fix the display area, as the user should be able to scroll the web-page normally, and the pop-up display area move with the rest of the elements on the page.

Once this is accomplished, I will want to make the pop-up area draggable, so the suggested solution(s) should be compatible with doing this. I plan on using [How TO - Create a Draggable HTML Element](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp) rather than using a jQuery or other type library.  This way I can optimize the code for the pop-up element that is the only draggable item on the page.

Thank you

Comment: Share your code....

Comment: My code is very lengthy and complex, so cutting it down to show just the problem I need help with is very difficult.  However, I looked at position: fixed again, changed the position style from absolute to fixed, and it works well enough.  My initial thought was that the pop-up would open near the top of the viewport, but then scroll normally with the rest of the page when the vertical scroll-bar was used, which the latter doesn't happen with fixed, but the fact that the pop-up stays in view isn't actually bad.  The user just has to close the pop-up to completely see the list again.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. Then I found a CSS trick which I used.

```css
.elements:nth-last-child(-n + 3) {
        // Insert CSS you want to apply
}

.elements:nth-last-child(n + 3) {
        // Insert CSS you want to apply
}
```

It helped me achieve the desired solution. Without any change in JavaScript and View. You just have to do calculations with `n` number.

For reference you can use below documentation -
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child